# Dojo textBox doesn't accept whitespace

Tags: textbox, javascript, dojo

I'm working with no experience on a Dojo project and don't know which version I'm working on.

There is a textBox for a search form which doesn't accept whitespace. I searched in this documentation for a solution, but no method seems to be applicable. http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/TextBox

So my question is: is it possible to accept whitespace in a textBox form or is it just possible with a ValidationTextBox?

```
me.filterBox = new TextBox({
            style: 'margin-bottom: 0',
            class: 'STQuicksearch',
            trim: false,
            intermediateChanges: true,
            placeHolder: 'Quick search'
         });
```

Edit:
There is no difference between setting trim false or true. But that's not my problem: I need to put whitespace between multiple words. Trim only removes leading and trailing whitespace!

Comment: Can you please add some code? It's easier to give an answer if we can see what you have tried. But i think vogomatix is right with his answer and "trim" will help you. Regards

Comment: Thanks for your message. I added some code. Trim is not what I want, I need whitespace between multiple words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coded a working solution:

```
me.filterBox = new TextBox({   
   ...
   onKeyDown: function(e) { 
      if (e.keyCode === keys.SPACE) {
          this.set('value', this.get('value')+' ');
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully in the documentation, you will find that the TextBox has a `trim` property, which removes leading and trailing whitespace if `true`. Setting this to `false` will hopefully give you the desired result.