# Can not insert whitespace in Dojo textbox

Tags: textbox, dojo, whitespace, dojox.grid.datagrid

I insert `dijit.form.TextBox` in dojo DataGrid

```
function getValue(value, rowIndex, cell) {
    var myTextBox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
        value: value,
        style: "width:60px",
        onChange: function(event){
            var itemId = grid.getItem(rowIndex).id[0];
            dojo.forEach(store._arrayOfAllItems, function(selectedItem) {
                if(selectedItem! = null && itemId == selectedItem.id[0]) {
                    selectedItem.col4[0]=event;
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
    return myTextBox;
}
```

[image]

I can not insert whitespace in this textbox in any place. Please help me fix it.

Comment: I used solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574765/dojo-textbox-doesnt-accept-whitespace but isntead keys.SPACE I used 32